# jquery : Change background color when the function is started and completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In my webpage I have a function `submitFileUpload()` that gets called when  button `aws-upload-submit` is clicked as can be seen from the below code.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
$(function() {
  submitFileUpload();
})

function submitFileUpload() {
  $('#aws-upload-submit').click(function() {
    //start displaying spinner here   
    //   $("*").css("background-color","yellow");                                                            
    loadfiles(); //around 1 min - 2 min of synchronous processing                                                               
    // $("*").css("background-color","green"); 
    //stop displaying spinner here
  })
}
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" id="aws-upload-submit">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

*Ideally I  would like to display a spinner that will be shown when the function begins and will be hidden when the function exits.*

Instead of spinner I thought of atleast changing the css background color property..i.e change the background color to yellow during function beginning and at the end change the background color to green after the function has completed.

When the function ran though, it just displayed green..

Most of the posts I looked up online were with respect to ajax but in my case submitFileUpload() is not an ajax function.

Is there a way to change the background color between the function start and end ?

Comment: You'll want to make use of a **promise** to know when the file upload has finished. You would set the colour when starting the request, then revert the colour inside of the return from the promise.

Answer (score 1):

Did you can use interval?

```
If(loadFiles()){
setInterval(Function("changeYellow();"), 60000);
}
```

Or try to use callback of function.